# Esper chain-repeat a followed-by pattern n times?

Tags: stream, complex-event-processing, esper

Is it possible to chain-repeat a followed-by pattern n times?

What I want to achieve is this pattern:

```
every a=A 
-> b=B(b.price < a.price) 
-> c=C(c.price < b.price) 
-> d=D(d.price < c.price) 
-> e=E(e.price < d.price) 
-> f=F(f.price < e.price) 
-> g=G(g.price < f.price)
...
```

If I for example write the pattern below, not every item get compared as above. (B is never compared with C, D is never compared with E, and so on.)

```
[16] (a=A -> b=B(b.price < a.price))
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the statement object model to build the EPL statement. What I'm referring to is in [1]. Match-recognize has a nice repeat "{16}" so that is another alternative.
[1] http://espertech.com/esper/release-6.1.0/esper-reference/html_single/index.html#api-soda